# How to close files that are opened in an external function

Tags: c, stdio, resource-leak

I am using a pre-compiled C library function (while coding myself in C++) which opens a file without closing it. I confirmed this by looking at the process's file descriptor list in **/proc/{PID}/fd.**
Each time i call the function, a file descriptor pointing the same file is created.

My problem is that i have to do a huge amount of iterations over that function and it eventually crashes because of that.

Of course, i have no pointer on the file stream so i can not use fclose.

I tried using fcloseall() but it does not close any of the streams that are open.

Here is some minimal code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
const int MAX_ITERATIONS = 10000;
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATIONS ; i++){
   result = Call(...);
   int closed = fcloseall();
}
```

here, closed is allways equal to 0 and the number of file descriptors never diminishes.

Is there another way of forcing those file streams to be closed or do i need to completely stop the program in order to destroy them?

Comment: Does it open **streams** (as with `fopen`) or **file descriptors** (as with `open`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try manually closing those file descriptors:

```
int fd, next_fd, next_fd2;
next_fd = dup(STDIN_FILENO);
close(next_fd);

// call that function which forgets to close its file descriptors

next_fd2 = dup(STDIN_FILENO);
close(next_fd2);
for(fd = next_fd; fd < next_fd2; ++fd)
    close(fd);
```

Note that this method is not thread-safe because it may close file descriptors opened by other threads.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code does not seem to do anything... I am getting the same self expanding file descriptor list... I will update my question to add the list

Comment: it seems that STDIN_FILENO always returns 0. Also, file descriptor 0 points /dev/pts/17. I have no idea what this is but it is not used directly by my program neither the SDK.

Comment: @Simon.L `STDIN_FILENO` is a macro that _expands_ to 0.

Comment: I am sorry if you thought that i was questionning your code. I am sure it works in your environement but in my case it does not. i have no idea why but this is clearly not the first problem i had with this library which is full of bugs and it truly pains me.

Comment: I solved my problem with this code which is really not elegant nor efficient but it seems to work:                                                             for (int fd = 3; fd < getdtablesize(); fd++)
    close(fd);

Comment: The code described uses `dup` to determine the next available file descriptor number and presumes that your library will leave a contiguous set of numbers open. If the library is closing some, but not all of its handles then this will not work.It may also close some unexpected file numbers if other code has previously opened a number of files, and then only closed the first one.

Comment: You could safely scan `/proc/self/fd/` before and after the call, then close the new entries, though that won't play nice multi-threaded. This is a lesser issue than the above code which might close other handles in the current thread.